# Binomial Logistic regression to Compare results of multiple methods to a known value

Tags: regression, logistic, categorical-data, binomial-distribution

I have a "known value" (recorded by a field observer) which I want to compare several methods of data collection with to test for significant differences between methods.

Methods: 
2 points along a trail each had 2 cameras (different brands) set at an "Optimized" point and a "randomized" point. Meanwhile a field observer recorded the number of people passing the cameras with different activities (bike/walk/etc).

I want to compare a binomial result (i.e. 0/1 for failure/success at capturing bikers with the cameras) with the known value (obtained through field observation). I'd like to compare (1) all optimized and all randomized with the known value and (2) optimized brand A and optimized brand B with the known value.

I've tried binomial logistic regression but I think I'm running into an issue with the fact that all optimized points is 4 times the number of observations as the known value.

Is this the correct test for this question, or could someone suggest a more appropriate method?

Comment: 1. How do the optimized and randomized points figure into the model? 2. "I think I'm running into an issue with the fact that all optimized points is 4 times the number of observations as the known value." Are you saying here that the values for all optimized points are "fail?"